# Why is <c:forEach> not working with Ajax request in JSP Spring?

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, controller

I am fetching some data with a Ajax request in my main JSP page.

Snippet of **main.jsp**

```
function gu(){
    $.get('/admin/getAllUsers', {}, function(data) {
        console.log(data); // see below
        $("#allUsersData").html(data);
    });
}
```

In my Spring controller I add all the users to a different JSP page.

Snippet of **MainController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/getAllUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllUsers(Model model){
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    System.out.println(users.size()); // output: 3
    model.addAttribute("allUsers", users);

    return "data/all-users";
}
```

Now in **all-users.jsp** I have a `<c:forEach>` which is supposed to load all users in a html table:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:if test="${not empty allUsers}">
            <c:forEach items="${allUsers}" var="usr">
                <tr>
                    <td>${usr.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${usr.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${usr.username}</td>
                    <td>${usr.creationDate}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, when I add the html coming from the request to my main JSP page, an empty table is shown. When I log the result of the Ajax request I find that the user data is inserted in the all-users.jsp:

```
<c:if test="true">
    <c:forEach items="[User{id=1, username='username1', firstName='John', lastName='Doe', roles=[Role{id=1, name='ROLE_USER'}], creationDate=2018-02-19T08:58:13.333}, User{id=2, username='username2', firstName='John2', lastName='Doe2', roles=[Role{id=3, name='ROLE_USER'}], creationDate=2018-02-19T08:58:13.471}]" var="usr">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Why is it happening that the data is loaded into the data JSP page, but not shown when appending it to the main JSP page?

Comment: "When I log the result of the Ajax request I find:" - Shouldn't the result be html? What you have posted is not html.

Comment: @Saurabh I totally agree, but it actually is what is getting logged in the console.

Comment: Can you add more details about view resolver specific beans that you have defined and servlet mapping definitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you check, maybe you haven't included the core tag library in your JSP file.
You will do this by inserting the following Line at the top of your file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: Of course, I thought it was not necessary because I had it in my main JSP file. Thanks a lot!